# Send Image as JSON String to Webservice

Tags: json, web-services, base64

I am using Spring MVC Restful Webservice. I need to send an image to the server as a JSON String. So I have encoded the image as string using Base64 and sent through json object.
While received at the server side image string is not received completely. Actually at the client side the image string length is 40000,but at server side it is around 1000.

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks,
Naresh.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally solved it myself, while sending the json string it is breaking so it was not received at server side.

Comment: can u pls help me how you resolve it i have also same problem

Comment: How can you accept the answer without showing what you did?